# creating the cakephp admin section for entire website

Tags: cakephp, control-panel

i have created the front of the website by baking the MVC and done the coding also, at that time i haven't backed the admin section.

Now i want to add admin section.which is the best method to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I am running thru the same issue as you. I have create several controllers (articles, users, fotos, etc), but now I have the need to create an admin section before moving forward. After asking questions here, reading the cookbook and doing some research online this is what I think is the best approach:

1. Create a `control panel controller` or whatever you want to call it, where you can have an action called `admin_index` or `admin_display`. This action should act like the home.ctp from the pages controller. Just use admin action so all other users should are denied access to this controller. I would have things there like, latest comments, latest users, visits graphs, comments needing approval, etc. [This is an example on how to approach this.](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/12/16/how-to-build-a-dashboard-for-your-application-in-cakephp/)
2. Enable `Routing.prefixes` in your `core.php` file. (You can find instructions about this in the CakePHP cookbook)
3. Create admin actions in your controllers such as `admin_index, admin_add`
4. Create code in the app_controller where `admin` is redirected to the `control panel controller` on login
5. At last, make a `admin layout` and make sure the `control panel controller` and all `admin actions` use this layout. In this layout you should create a menu that links to all `admin actions` somewhere in the header and underneath you should have a section where all admin action will be displayed. [Theme Fores](http://themeforest.net/searches?term=control%20panel&type=files)t should have some good control panel examples you can use.

I will be working in my admin system sometime this weekend and If I am successful using this approach I will post the code back in here.

To note: I am also learning CakePHP and although I love it, I can still make beginners mistakes. One thing I would suggest you dont do is start using plugins this early in your game. It will discourage you and sink any hope you have in being successful programming in Cake

Answer (score 1):

there is much more simpler way for this approach....We can use current_controller fie and define admin_function_you_want..There is no need for creating a new controller for admin..you can find notes about it in cake php book

Answer (score 1):

The best method would be to create your own admin panel, however it would be time consuming at time you can also try out a cakephp plugin and looking at the inner coding learn how it is done.

You can give a try with https://github.com/Maldicore/Admin

Answer (score 0):

You can write yours by using [tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1527/Tutorials-Examples) or you can use [one of the existing](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bancer/). If you write yourself [Auth](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication) component must be implemented as a minimum requirement.